# Unable to create react app : npm stuck at “found 0 vulnerabilities”

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am creating a react app after passing the command create-react-app app-name the npm stops at found 0 vulnerabilities. However, my directory has been created with 2 files package.json and package-lock.json and a folder node-modules.

Comment: For newer react versions, use `npx create-react-app app-name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and installing Node v12.13.1 x86 instead of x64 I managed to create React app!

Answer (score 0):

At this point `create-react-app` is initializing the git repository and it usually takes quite a while and no output is shown then. You have be patient and wait longer :)